# Is there any way to alternate the backgroundColor of leading, CircleAvatar

Tags: flutter, android-listview, background-color

I am displaying the data of api response into ListView.builder, ListTile, i want to alternate the background color of CircleAvatar, let say if api response data lenght is 5, then in 1st and 2nd Circle avatar background color will be same to 4th and 5th (if there are 3 alternative colors)

```
 ListTile(
    leading:  CircleAvatar(
    radius: 25,
 backgroundColor:Colors.red
```

please help any idea to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
int i = 0;

ListView(...

 Color c = Colors.red;

 if(i == 0) i++;
 else if(i == 1) {
   c = Colors.blue;
   i++;
 } else if(i == 2) {
   c = Colors.yellow;
   i = 0;
 }

 ListTile(
    leading:  CircleAvatar(
    radius: 25,
 backgroundColor: c
```

Answer (score 1):

the alternating logic of 1,2 and 4,5 is a little bit confusing for me but from what I understand, you could use the builders index for changing colors. Something like this:

```
ListView.builder(
itemCount: dummyList.length,
itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
    leading:  CircleAvatar(
        radius: 25,
        backgroundColor: [1,2,4,5].contains(index) ? Colors.red : Colors.blue
        ),
    ),
);
```

you may need to change the logic to your needs. For example color for only last two would be:

```
[dummyList.length - 1, dummyList.length].contains(index) ? Colors.red : Colors.blue
```

or for just even numbers would be

```
(index % 2) == 0 ? Colors.red : Colors.blue
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you change value like 0 and 1 your need and color also:

```
//declare one varibale 
var lead;

backgroundColor: (lead == '0')? Colors.blue: (lead == '1')? Colors.red: Colors.green,
```